# NopCommerce - OutPutCaching not working on Full/Parent Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

If I apply `[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]` on Any Child action `[ChildActionOnly]` it works just fine. but if Apply caching on a main action.
It will keep hitting the action every time I refresh the page.

I created a new controller which inherits MVC "`BaseController`" instead of inheriting  Nopcommerce "`BasePublicController`".
But still no Luck.

```
public class CacheController : BaseController
    {
        [ OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
        public ActionResult testCache( )
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Now if I create a brand new an independent MVC project  caching works just fine.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve and what you tried. Show your code where it is relevant.

Comment: @Raidri. Which part of the question needs more detail? the code is posted though

Comment: Down votes?  is it just a habit OR I am missing  something, explaining my problem?

Comment: @Raidri I did not hear back from you.